# Unable to load your default controller. error in live code igniter hmvc site

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have display error on newly site when i publice on live like this

Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

And its project develop in HMVC code igniter framework and its project well work on my localhost wamp server but not in live hosting server

following my directory structure and basic path configuration
[image]

please tell me any mistake on live configuration on my web site project code
thank you

Comment: show me your folder project constructor

Comment: means default controllers constructor function?

Comment: class Login extends MX_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('UserRegister', 'register');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
}

Comment: HMVC `$route['default_controller'] = 'login/login/index/';` I see you have capital letter for controllers folder name should be `modules > login >  controllers` not `modules > login >  Controllers`

Comment: i have change folder name in small later like this modules > login > controllers and controller file name in first later capital later like Login.php also change $route['default_controller'] = 'login/login/index/'; but not working

Comment: You might have wrong htaccess also make sure htaccess out side of application folder in the main directory

Comment: my .htaccess are our side application directory

Answer (score 0):

Rename to `Login.php` and

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Login/index'; //Controller/method
//Default controller do not put in sub directory
```

and in the controller `class Login extends MX_Controller ...`

In linux, capital letter and normal letter is very important

Comment: `modules > login > controllers` if your controller is `class Login extends MX_Controller`, try this one
`$route['default_controller'] = 'login/Login/index';`